# Typescript manual property assignment causing type error with typed ngrx actions

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm trying to introduce typed actions into my application. I've tried these two class declarations. The first one works fine, but the second one causes my IDE (WebStorm) to complain with the message `Unresolved variable payload`. Is it just my IDE being stupid or is it reporting an issue correctly? I prefer the latter solution because I feel it is more explicit, making it clearer to the developer to know what is required in order to create a valid action.

WORKING:

```
export class OrdersGetAction implements Action {
    type = ActionTypes.ORDERS_GET;

    constructor(public payload: number) {}
}
```

NOT WORKING - `Unresolved variable payload`:

```
export class OrdersGetAction implements Action {

    public payload;
    public type = ActionTypes.ORDERS_GET;

    constructor(clientId: number) {
        this.payload = clientId;
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find a resolution. Once I declared a type on the payload property itself, the IDE stopped moaning. My changes are shown here:

```
export class OrdersGetAction implements Action {

    public payload: number; // number TYPE HERE FIXES THINGS
    public type = ActionTypes.ORDERS_GET;

    constructor(clientId: number) {
        this.payload = clientId;
    }
}
```